# archlinux:bless Font misplaced with Monaco

Tags: fonts, archlinux

I had changed the Font: Monaco Regular with Gnome 3.
ps: all fonts config include,like : Monospaced ,Interface,File,Window Title fonts
But I found  bless give me a  misplaced fonts display

[image]